# Swift string to ascii array Cyrillic

Tags: swift, string, ascii, cyrillic

This string extension works with Latin characters, but doesn't work with Cyrillic. Can someone explain why, and how can I fix it?

```
extension String {
    var asciiArray: [UInt32] {
        return unicodeScalars.filter{$0.isASCII}.map{$0.value}
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a sample input and the expected output? Converting  Cyrillic characters to ASCII makes no sense. Do you want UTF-8, Unicode scalars, ... ? – Perhaps you just need to remove the filter?

Comment: *"works with Latin characters, but doesn't work with Cyrillic"* - in what way does it work and not work?

Comment: Cyrillic characters are not ASCII characters. ASCII only covers the first 255 characters out of all possible Unicode characters.

Comment: You're trying to create an `asciiArray` to represent non-ascii characters. How is that supposed to work?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing the original [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) standard with one of its cyrillic extensions (such as [KOI-8R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI8-R)).  The original ASCII is 7-bit, whereas an extension would use up the codes above 127 (and up to 255) for its purposes.

Swift's `isASCII` property on `UnicodeScalar` type indicates whether a scalar is from the original ASCII.